# D3 Changing the width attribute of an object depending on it's child

Tags: javascript, css, d3.js

I am trying to change the width of the entire frame of something in D3 after it has already been created, depending on the width of some text inside of it (so that it doesn't get cut off). However, I'm having trouble returning the width of the text element.

The body looks like so:

```
this.body = d3.select("#" + this.placeholderName)
  .append("svg:svg")
  .attr("class", "gauge")
  .attr("width", this.config.size)
  .attr("height", this.config.size + 150);
```

The text inside the body looks like this:

```
this.body.append("svg:text")
  .attr("x", this.config.cx - 60)
  .attr("y", this.config.cy / 2 + fontSize / 2)
  .attr("dy", fontSize / 2)
  .attr("text-anchor", "start")
  .text(this.config.label)
  .style("font-size", fontSize + "px")
  .style("fill", "#333")
  .style("stroke-width", "0px")
```

Finally, I change the width of the frame with this. What would I need to put as the second argument here?

```
this.body.attr("width", <WIDTH OF TEXT ABOVE>);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, when you create your text element, give it a class or id so you can easily select it later.

Lets say you give it `.attr('class', 'bodyText')`.

Then you can get its length using [`SVGTextContentElement.getComputedTextLength()`](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/text.html#__svg__SVGTextContentElement__getComputedTextLength)

You can get this value for your text node by using `selection.node()` to grab the actual text element from a d3 selection, and then calling the method on the node. Like this:

```
var textLength = d3.select('.bodyText').node().getComputedTextLength();
```

Then you can use this value when setting your width property.

Comment: Thanks, in the end it was the selection that was confusing me. Works (somewhat) now. The text still gets cut off it it's too long for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

Have  you tried this:

```
 this.body.append("svg:text").attr("id","textValue")
```

and

```
var w=d3.select("#textValue").attr("width");
```

Now

```
this.body.attr("width", w);
```

I think it should work.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand this properly. How would this calculate the width of the this.config.label text (which is defined elsewhere)? Wouldn't I need to call a function that will return the size of the text back to me, such as getBBox().width or getComputedTextLength()?